# Find regex pattern match string have multiple condition?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some strings formatted as follows:

```
1=case1,case2,..caseN;2=case1,..,caseN;3=case1, ..,caseN
```

Note: `comma ";"` is used to separate cases and `case1, case2` are anything like strings, number doesn't matter their type.

I want to find regex pattern to match string

```
1=home,house;2=abc;3=2019,2021
```

however, it will not match the following:

```
1=home,;2=abc;3=2019,2021 (Excess comma mark at case 1)
1=;2=abc,2012;3=          (must 1=..; not 1=;)
1=home,age;2              (must 2=.. not 2)
2=home;;3=sea             (must ;3 not ;;3)
4=flower;k3=sea           (must 3= , not k3)
```

I tried with the pattern: `(\d+={1}[^;]+;)`. However, it will match if the backstring is not. 
Please show me the way.

Many thanks!

Comment: the 5 examples are the illformed that the regex has to refuse?

Comment: Hi, @Berto99 yes, it will not match the 5 strings above.

Comment: Hi @Mandy8055, thanks for the question!. Comma is not allowed at the end of the string.

Comment: FYI `;` is called a semicolon

Comment: Whatis the final result? Boolean or `List<string, List<string>>`?

Comment: Hi, @WiktorStribiżew.  My desired result is boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this pattern helps you out:

```
^\b(?:(?:^|;)\d+=[^,;]+(?:,[^,;]+)*)+$
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ssx9pL/7)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `\b` - Word-boundary.
- `(?:` - Opening 1st non-capture group.

  - `(?:`- Opening 2nd non-capture group.

    - `^|;` - Alternation between start string ancor or semi-colon.
  - `)` - Closing 2nd non-capture group.
  - `\d+=` - One or more digits followed by a `=`.
  - `[^,;]+` - Negated character class, any character other than comma or semicolon one or more times.
  - `(?:` - Opening 3rd non-capture group.

    - `,` - A comma.
    - `[^,;]+` - Negated character class, any character other than comma or semicolon one or more times.
    - `)*` - Close 3rd non-capture group and make it match zero or more times.
- `)+` - Close 1st non-capture group and make sure it's matches one or more times.
- `$` - End string ancor.

---

[image]

<sup>**Note:** I went with a negated character class since you mentioned *"case1, case2 are anything like strings, number doesn't matter their type"*, therefor I read there can be spaces, special characters or any kind other than comma and semicolon.</sup>

Comment: [Your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/Ssx9pL/6) a string starting with `;`

Comment: I like this approach!. I tried to add \b after the caret and your pattern work for me now. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Mindex, that is good news! Good catch on the starting semicolon from Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

This works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JVCgIM/5)

```
^(?:\d=(?:\w{1,},)*(?:\w{1,});)*(?:\d=(?:\w{1,},)*\w{1,})$
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I will try your pattern!

Comment: @Mindex thanks, if there are cases where it fails, let me know and i'll fix it

Comment: @Mindex the regex is changed

Comment: This is matching `1=,,,,,abc`

Comment: @Toto you are probably using the old version, please check again

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\d+=[a-z\d]+(?:,[a-z\d]+)*(?:;|$))+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zpp87i/1/)

```
^                : match beginning of string
(?:              : begin nc group  
  \d+=[a-z\d]+   : match 1+ digits, then '=' then 1+ lc letters or digits
  (?:,[a-z\d]+)  : match ',' then 1+ lc letters or digits in nc group
  *              : execute nc group 0+ times 
  (?:;|$)        : match ';' or end of string
)+               : end nc group and execute 1+ times
$                : match end of string
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. Your pattern works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if c# supports recursive pattern, but, if it does, use:

```
^(\d+=\w+(?:,\w+)*)(?:;(?1))*$
```

if it doesn't:

```
^\d+=\w+(?:,\w+)*(?:;\d+=\w+(?:,\w+)*)*$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/0a2wn3/1)

Comment: If recursion is allowed, then this is very cool indeed. I have no experience with `c#` but you got my vote =)

Comment: .NET does not support recursion.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply,  I will try your pattern!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. your second pattern worked for me.